# Rails cannot find files that contain open square bracket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jplayer

This is my first question at stackoverflow.
I am building a simple music streamer based on JPlayer's playlists and Rails. Basically I copy my mp3s into a root directory, and I index the files by artists. Then I use a JQuery autocomplete for searching the artist, and I generate a playlist for that artist getting back a JSon array with the mp3s. Everything works fine unless a dir or a file contains an open square bracket.

Started GET "/music/[hello.mp3" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Nov 07 11:48:09 +0100 2011
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/music/[hello.mp3"):

Everything works fine with /music/hello.mp3

I can reproduce the error with or without symlinks, and only with [, but not with ]. I've already tried to escape with \[ or \\[. It doesn't solve the problem.
I'm using rails 3.1.1, ruby 1.8.7.

index.js.erb contains

```
new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, [
    <%= @titles.html_safe %>
], {
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

@titles contains

```
{
    title:"1 - hello",
    mp3:"music/[hello.mp3"
},
{
    title:"2 - goodbye",
    mp3:"music/[goodbye.mp3"
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Showing the relevant code would certainly help :)

Comment: I guess [ needs to be url-converted for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you give an example on how to url-convert [ ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any working answer is really appreciated!

Comment: Hey Haspemulator, have got it working eventually? I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGI.escape` on the string for the file to escape the sensitive elements.  (RDoc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape)

```
CGI.escape('music/[hello.mp3')
=> "music%2F%5Bhello.mp3"
```

Comment: I've tried both URI.encode(@titles.html_safe) and URI.encode(@titles). Same problem.

Comment: Try using the CGI.escape method instead.  URI apparently doesn't care about brackets for some reason.

Comment: CGI.escape('music/[hello.mp3') doesn't work either. ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "music/%5Bhello.mp3"):

Comment: Is the 'music' folder within the public folder of the Rails app? It'll look for static resources there first before attempting to route to the 'music' controller.

Comment: Yes the music folder is in the public folder. What should I try to do?

Comment: Perhaps `config.serve_static_assets = true` isn't set in your environment?  Nevertheless, I wouldn't suggest serving up something as large as a music file from Ruby; let Apache or Nginx deal with that (it's much faster).